# Django: Keep a persistent reference to an object?

Tags: python, django

I'm happy to accept that this might not be possible, let alone sensible, but is it possible to keep a persistent reference to an object I have created?

For example, in a few of my views I have code that looks a bit like this (simplified for clarity):

```
api = Webclient()
api.login(GPLAY_USER,GPLAY_PASS)
url = api.get_stream_urls(track.stream_id)[0]

client = mpd.MPDClient()
client.connect("localhost", 6600)
client.clear()
client.add(url)
client.play()
client.disconnect()
```

It would be really neat if I could just keep one reference to `api` and `client` throughout my project, especially to avoid repeated api logins with `gmusicapi`. Can I declare them in `settings.py`? (I'm guessing this is a terrible idea), or by some other means keep a connection to them that's persistent?

Ideally I would then have functions like `get_api()` which would check the existing object was still ok and return it or create a new one as required.

Comment: Why not storing these two objects into a [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) file?

Comment: @Paco Interesting idea. It seems odd, but I can't imagine why it wouldn't work, although I've never worked with pickles before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have anything that's instantiated once per application, because you'll almost certainly have more than one server process, and objects aren't easily shared across processes. However, one per process is definitely possible, and worthwhile. To do that, you only need to instantiate it at module level in the relevant file (eg views.py). That means it will be automatically instantiated when Django first imports that file (in that process), and you can refer to it as a global variable in that file. It will persist as long as the process does, and when as new process is created, a new global var will be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't persist the object reference, but you can store something either in memory django cache or in memcached django cache.

Django Cache
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/

See also
[Creating a Persistent Data Object In Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345257/creating-a-persistent-data-object-in-django/2348841)

Answer (score 0):

1. You could make them properties of your application object or of some
   other application object that is declared at the top level of your
   project - before anything else needs it.
2. If you put them into a class that gets instantiated on the first
   import and is then just used on the rest it can be imported by
   several modules and accessed.

Either way they would have a life of the length of the execution.

Comment: Could you be a bit more Django-specific?

Comment: Sorry - I don't use Django at the moment.