# Instantiate object "at module level" in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to use an [mpd client](https://github.com/Mic92/python-mpd2) in a Django project and would like to avoid having more connections to the mpd server than necessary. I think the easiest way to achieve this is to reuse the mpd-client object instead of creating a new object for every request.

In short, I'd like to do something very similar to this: [Django: Keep a persistent reference to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130698/django-keep-a-persistent-reference-to-an-object).

@daniel-roseman states this is easy to achieve by simply instantiating the object at module level. However, as a python-newbie I don't quite understand what that means.

So far I have created a module (see below) that would reconnect to mpd in case of a disconnect and saved this module to `<Project>/<app>/lib/MPDProxy.py`.

How would I instantiate this (mpd-)object at module level?

```
# MPDProxy.py
from mpd import MPDClient, MPDError

class MPDProxy:
    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=6600, timeout=10):
        self.client = MPDClient()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.client.timeout = timeout
        self.connect(host, port)

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.client.connect(host, port)
        self.client.consume(1) # when we call self.client.next() the previous stream is deleted from the playlist
        if len(self.client.playlist()) > 1:
            cur =  (self.client.playlist()[0][6:])
            self.client.clear()
            self.add(cur)

    def add(self, url):
        try:
            self.client.add(url)
        except ConnectionError:
            self.connect(self.host, self.port)
            self.client.add(url)

    def play(self):
        try:
            self.client.play()
        except ConnectionError:
            self.connect(self.host, self.port)
            self.client.play()

    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.client.stop()
        except ConnectionError:
            self.connect(self.host, self.port)
            self.client.stop()

    def next(self):
        try:
            self.client.next()
        except ConnectionError:
            self.connect(self.host, self.port)
            self.client.next()

    def current_song(self):
        try:
            return self.client.currentsong()
        except ConnectionError:
            self.connect(self.host, self.port)
            return self.client.current_song()

    def add_and_play(self, url):
        self.add(url)

        if self.client.status()['state'] != "play":
            self.play()

        self.next()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just mean the bottom level of that module, at the same indentation as the "from mpd..." and "class MPDProxy..." lines.

So, at the bottom of the file, without indenting at all, put `proxy = MPDProxy()` - and now you can reference that instance from anywhere by importing it with `from lib.MPDProxy import proxy`.

Comment: just one thing: shouldn't it be `from .lib.MPDProxy import proxy`? without the leading `.` it wouldn't work at my environment.