# Django: Machine learning model in server side?

Tags: django, machine-learning, redis, celery

I have a `Word2Vec` model(One of Machine learning model) and could get this pre-trained model by filename :

```
model = Word2Vec.load(fname)
```

So, I can get some prediction by using this model:

prediction = model.predict(X)

What I'm trying to do is to get request(including query word) from user and query this data to my pre-trained model and get prediction so that server could send response with this prediction data. This process should occur every time user send queries, so this pre-trained model should always be in memory.

To implement this, I think I have to use `Redis`, `Celery` kinda thing, but as I know of, `Celery` is working asynchronously with `Django` web application, so it would not be suitable for what I want to do...

How can I implement this function in my `Django` application?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a tutorial how to deploy machine learning models with Django: https://deploymachinelearning.com with code available at github: https://github.com/pplonski/my_ml_service

Answer (score 9):

You don't actually need Redis or celery for this.

Before I post the solution using Django, I should mention that if you only need a web interface for your ML project, that is, you don't need Django's fancy ORM, admin, etc, you should go with Flask. It's perfect for your use case.

---

### Solution using Flask:

It's very easy to store your trained model in memory using Flask:

```
# ...
# your Flask application code
# ...
# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Word2Vec.load(fname)
    app.run()
```

If you're interested, the complete example is [here](https://medium.com/@amirziai/a-flask-api-for-serving-scikit-learn-models-c8bcdaa41daa).

---

### Solution using Django:

You can utilise Django's cache framework to store your model. First, activate the local memory cache backend. [Instructions are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching).

Now, you'll need to store your model in the cache.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

model_cache_key = 'model_cache' 
# this key is used to `set` and `get` 
# your trained model from the cache

model = cache.get(model_cache_key) # get model from cache

if model is None:
    # your model isn't in the cache
    # so `set` it
    model = Word2Vec.load(fname) # load model
    cache.set(model_cache_key, model, None) # save in the cache
    # in above line, None is the timeout parameter. It means cache forever

# now predict
prediction = model.predict(...)
```

You can keep the above code in your views, but I'd rather you create a separate file for that and then import this file in you views.

You can find the full example is [on this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170610090440/http://www.wiliamkudaka.com/2016/06/29/django-and-scikit-learn-model-persistence-joblib/).

Comment: The link has expired, can you provide an example of the Django solution? Thanks.

Comment: @ascetic652 You can view that blog post in [this Wayback snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20170610090440/http://www.wiliamkudaka.com/2016/06/29/django-and-scikit-learn-model-persistence-joblib/).

Answer (score 0):

Seconded that you don't need a Redis and celery for this.  The most simple solution is outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130698/django-keep-a-persistent-reference-to-an-object) by Daniel Roseman.

This approach is also practical for if you have an object which cannot be serialized/ pickled (as is necessary to take advantage of django's cache).

All you need to do is instantiate the `model` object before your views in `views.py`, that way `model` is called one time (when views.py is imported) and the class/function based views will be able to access the `model`.

This would look like this in your question:

```
# views.py
model = Word2Vec.load(fname)

class WordView(View):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    # make a prediction based on request
    prediction = model.predict(self.request.something)

    return prediction
```